# JavaFX ScrollPane vs. TabView filling space

Tags: layout, javafx, tabs, tabpanel, scrollpane

I've placed some content inside a TabPane's tab, but the TabPane's width seems to me being equal to the longest element inside the tab (the longest element is not visible on the picture).

The TabPane is loaded to a ScrollPane via FXMLLoader.load(), that's why I would expect it to fill the whole space, not just the size of the longest element inside..

[image]

How could I make the TabPane fill all available space?

Loader:

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("View.fxml"));
        Node tp = loader.load();
        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
        sp.setContent(tp);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(sp, 300, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
```

View.fxml:

```
<TabPane tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane />
      </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane />
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
sp.setContent(tp);
sp.setFitWidth(true);
```

Comment: Thank you! The correct method name is sp.setFitToWidth(true); if anyone else is looking for the solution...